# Help solving a simple ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE
$$h'(t) = -k \sqrt{h(t)} \,,$$

where $k$ is a positive constant. Suppose we also know that $h(0)=16$ and $h(30)=4$. How do we find the function $h(t)$?

**Attempt:** we could try integrating the ODE between $t=0$ and $t=30$:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{30} h'(s) ds &= -k \int_0^{30} \sqrt{h(s)} ds 
\end{align*}
the left side of which is $ h(30) - h(0) = 12$.

For the right side, we can use u-substitution with $u= \sqrt{h(s)}$, and $du = h'(s) ds$ to get
\begin{align*}
-k \int_0^{30} \sqrt{h(s)} ds &= -k \int_0^{30} \sqrt{u} \frac{1}{h'(s)} du 
\\
&= -k \int_0^{30} \sqrt{u} \frac{1}{-k\sqrt{h(t)}} du
\\
&= -k \int_0^{30} \frac{1}{-k} du 
\\
&= -30k \,.  
\end{align*}

Hence $12 = -30k$. But we don't get any more information about $h(t)$.

**attempt 2:**

separation of variables:
$$ \frac{dh}{\sqrt{h}} = -kdt $$

integrating both sides,
$$
\int_0^{h(t)} \frac{dh}{\sqrt{h}} = -k\int_0^t ds
$$

$$2\sqrt{h(t)}  = -kt 
$$

so, $\sqrt{h(t)} = -\frac{kt}{2}$
which is weird because a square root is negative. If we square both sides then $h(t)$ is increasing in $t$ which isn't true from the original ODE.

Comment: Hint: the equation is equivalent to $\dfrac{h'(t)}{\sqrt{h(t)}}=-k$. Integrate respect to $h$ on the left and respect to $t$ on the right.

Comment: $du=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{h(s)}}h'(s)ds$

Comment: Shall we assume that k is some constant?

Comment: @DanAsimov yes. edited and also attempted the separation of variables, and got a weird result.

Comment: @900edges, You didn't apply proper limits, the limits corresponding to $t$ is $h(t)$ and that corresponding to $0$ is $h(0)=16$. Thus the result you should have obtained is $2\sqrt{h(t)}-2\sqrt{h(0)}=-kt$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $k$ is a constant, it is a separable ODE.so you can rewrite $$h'(t)=-k\sqrt{h(t)}\to \frac {dh(t)}{dt}=-k\sqrt{h(t)}\\\frac {dh(t)}{\sqrt{h(t)}}=-kdt$$then apply integral for $[0,t]  \ $ both sides then use and apply $h(0),h(30)$to find constants, to have $h(t)$ as an exact function
$$\int_0^{t} \frac{dh(s)}{\sqrt{h(s)}} = -k\int_0^t 1ds
\\2\sqrt{h(s)}|_0^t=-ks|_0^t\\2\sqrt{h(t)}-2\sqrt{h(0)}=-k(t-0)$$now apply $h(0)=16 \ $into result
$$2\sqrt{h(t)}-2\sqrt{16}=-kt\\
$$ now final step $t=30$

$$2\sqrt{h(30)}-2\sqrt{16}=-k(30)\\2(2)-2(4)=-30k\\k=\frac{-4}{-30}\to k=\frac {2}{15}$$and now
$$2\sqrt{h(t)}-2\sqrt{16}=-\frac 2{15}t$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really understand why the bounds on the left-side integral are $0$ and $t$. We're integrating wrt $h(s)$ so I thought the bounds should be something that $h(s)$ "attains"?

Comment: This is a common misconception. You integrate both sides w.r.t. $t$, but you can perform a trivial $u$-substitution in the integral in the LHS to change it to an integral that looks like $dh$. Doing it in this way helps keep your initial conditions in the correct place.

Comment: @900edges: when $t$ rise from $o \to t \ $ ,$h(t)$ go from $h(0)$ to $h(t)$

Comment: @900edges: Now you can finish it ?

Comment: So if the variable of integration on the left side is $h(s)$, then the bounds are REALLY $h(0)$ and $h(t)$. Ok

Comment: If $h=30$ as offered in the problem, then your last line gives $2*2 - 2*4 = -k*30$ so $k=-4/30$. Wait I thought $k$ was positive, and I'm still confused about what $h(t)$ is as a function of $t$.

Comment: @900edges: This means, you passed the misconception.

Comment: @900edges: i'll complete the answer

Answer (score 0):

(1) We are taking $\sqrt{y}$ hence $y$ can not be negative.

(2) We can move the terms to get $[dy/dx]^2=k^2y$

(3) Let $y=c_1x^n+\cdots$ , then $dy/dx=c_1nx^{n-1}$ & $[dy/dx]^2=c_1^2n^2x^{2n-2}$

Hence $n=2n-2$ & $c_1k^2=c_1^2n^2$
Hence $n=2$ & $c_1=k^2/4$

(4) Let the Solution be $y=k^2x^2/4+c_2x+c_3$

$[dy/dx]=k^2x/2+c_2$
$[dy/dx]^2=k^2x^2/4+c_2^2+c_2k^2x$

(5) Equate the terms with $k^2y$ to get the whole Solution :
$k^2c_2=c_2k^2$
$k^2c_3=c_2^2$

We then have 2 independent unknowns $c_1,c_2$ here ,  while $c_3,k$ are dependent on the other 2 unknowns.

(6) With the boundary conditions , we can get $k$ & $c_1,c_2,c_3$ , which we can plug into the original equation to check the consistency & verify the Solution.